# CORS rejecting requests from Fastly endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cors, fastly

Trying to troubleshoot, what I think is a, CORS issue.

Heroku us our host. Fastly is our CDN.

Browser console error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://myapp.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/aBcD--redacted--/image_0123456789.pdf' from origin 'https://www.myapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to `"*"`

[image: Fastly headers]

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Fastly document instructions for this here:
https://docs.fastly.com/en/guides/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing

It's also recommended that you `curl` your resource and check the response headers include the expected CORS header(s):
https://docs.fastly.com/en/guides/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing#test-it-out

If that's not the case, then I would suggest contacting support@fastly.com and providing your Service ID. They'll be happy to help investigate further.